# Displaying value and percentage on a stacked bar chart in Cognos 11.1.7

Tags: cognos-11, stacked-bar-chart

Can both the data value and the percentage be displayed when hovering over a stacked bar chart in Cognos 11.1.7?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome

> > Can both the data value and the percentage be displayed when hovering over a stacked bar chart

Would this work for you?

[image]

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cognos-analytics/11.1.0?topic=configurations-stacked-charts#ti_chart_stcked_config

Comment: Are you able to hover and see the values and percentage for each segment? The requirement I am trying to satisfy is that both the value and the 'percentage of category' are visible when hovering over each segment. I can specify that the label displays the 'percentage of category' on the chart, and then can view the value when hovering over, but I am not able to show both when hovering. What is driving the request to view when hovering is that some of the sections are very small, like the first one you have in 2022 in purple on the bottom, where the value is not visible.

Comment: Okay, so if you can see both measures on a chart that would meet your requirements?
Another way of saying this is one measure is so much larger, the other measure results in being a tiny slice sometimes.